# Lotus Notes error "entry not found in index or view's index not built"

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

Many users are working on the same Lotus Notes database. One user is facing an access issue with a particular letter field in the database. When he tried to access got the error "entry not found in index or view's index not built", but the other user can access it in their own IBM Notes. We had tried to refresh the database but still getting the same error. I have checked the database properties and the user has access reader and writer.Please suggest to me how we can resolve this issue.

Comment: does this letter filed compute with any formula ? if so check that. Else re-index the view or  try compact properties of database.

Comment: @Gopipuli Thank you. I have no idea if any logic behind this to access the particular fields. I have tried to re-index the view but it's not worked. I don't have access to compact properties.

Comment: It might be a Notes Client Cache issue. Remove the database icon with all replicas from user's workspace. Close and open Notes Client and add the database icons.

Comment: Pressing F9 or Shift+F9 from the view in Notes client will index the view and database. @Ravi

Comment: Yes, you can reindex a view with Shift-F9, but the bad or missing index could be any view in any database. You really have to look at the code to get an idea of where your problem is, an as @KnutHerrmann indicated, it could also be a cache issue.

Comment: Does the document have a Reader field on it?  That would prevent a user from seeing it as well.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried to rebuild the local workspace and server database but it's not worked. They have read and write access to the database. The  other team member are able to access with the same access.

Comment: @Ravi Please check the field property last tab whether you have placed some hide condition or something also do check the text property of the line for any sort of formula. Do you have any rules in acl ? if there any please check that too.